# Legendre Polynomials (Calculus Vol.2, Tom M. Apostol, Chapter 6, Exercise 6.21, 14)

Tags: calculus

(a) Use Rolle’s theorem to show that $P_n$ cannot have any multiple zeros in the open interval $(-1, 1)$. In other words, any zeros of $P_n$  wich lie in $(-1, 1)$, must be simple zeros.

- $P_n$ is the $n$-th Legendre Polynomial

Comment: Any thoughts? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $P_n$ has a zero $z\in(-1,1)$ of order $2$, i.e. $P_n(z)=P_n'(z)=0$.

Since $P_n$ satisfies the differential equation
$$\tag{1}
[(1-x^2)P_n'(x)]'+n(n+1)P_n(x)=0,
$$
we deduce that 
$$
(1-z^2)P_n''(z)-2zP_n'(z)+n(n+1)P_n(z)=0,
$$
i.e. $P_n''(z)=0$ because $z^2\ne 1$. By induction we have $P_n^{(k)}(z)=0$ for all $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n$.

Thus
$$
P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{P_n^{(k)}(z)}{k!}(x-z)^k=0 \quad \forall x, 
$$
i.e. $P_n\equiv0$. This cannot be because $\deg P_n=n$. Hence $z$ is a simple root.